# Using freemarker 'list' directive within a google maps function

Tags: google-maps, freemarker

I have the following list called 'locationList':

*[[lat:-6.2986514, lng:53.3324511, car_reg:161-D-XXXXXX], [lat:-7.259881, lng:53.041335, car_reg:151-D-YYYYY], [lat:-7.6273397, lng:53.3052366, car_reg:142-D-ZZZZZ]]*

Now, if I just do a simple iteration like this it works. (It outputs my three lines of coordinates.).

```
  <#list locationList as loc>
      <p>   Output: ${loc.lat} -- ${loc.lng} </p>
   </#list>
```

But when I try to use it within my google maps function, it won't work.  This is what I have:

```
function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {

 <#list locationList as loc>

    var latlng = {lat: ${loc.lat}, lng: ${loc.lng} };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
          });

  </#list>  
}
```

It works fine if I just write out manually three times what is contained within the freemarker list tags.

And I have tried everything I can think of. Can anyone help throw light on what is happening here?

EDIT - Whole script included below:

```
<script>


function initMap() {

    <#assign lat='53.328015' lng='-6.3743767' >

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: {lat: ${lat}, lng: ${lng} }
    });
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
      geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
    });
  }


function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {

     <#list locationList as loc>

    var latlng = {lat: ${loc.lat}, lng: ${loc.lng} };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
          });

    </#list>  
}

</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=REMOVED&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, always check what the actual output is (you should be able to do that in the web browser) and how that differs from what you write when you fill it manually. Also, check what JavaScript errors you get.

My blind guess is that the numbers are formatted for human audience, and thus aren't valid JavaScript literals. Use `?c` (as in `${loc.lat?c}`) to format for computer "audience".

Comment: I am used to server side programming. However I was using the console in chrome to track output. It is not reporting any errors.

I also tried your suggestion of ?c. Doesn'y work. But I already tried using an <#assign directive to state values and insert them the way I have done it here, and that worked ok.

So it must be something to do with the loop? I wondered about async and defer but changing that didn't help.

I am editing my post to include the entire script (although I have pulled out the infowindow stuff for the monment. Any help appreciatefd.

Comment: Check the generated JavaScript (means, all FreeMarker statements were already resolved in it). That's what I meant by "check what the actual output is".

Answer (score 0):

The code was fine. In constructing my list I had got longtitude and latitude the wrong way around. Apologies. I was looking in the entirely wrong place.